# Is it possible to migrate work item from different tenants

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

I have two organizations in Azure Devops, with different tenants, one in "@xpto" and the other in "@abcd", is it possible to migrate boards, work items, pipelines, repos from "@xpto" to "@abcd"?

I believe that in work items there may be a problem with those that are already directed to someone, as they are
different tenants, eg "marie@xpto.com" with "marie@abcd.com"

Answer (score 0):

For work items, you could export work items to CSV from org "@xpto" by query and delete the ID value column (Work item ID value is unique in each organizations)

[image]

After importing, you need the resolve the area path and assigned user issues. Check this link to check the error example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#import-new-work-items

For Private project repos, paste the URL and the PAT created from "@xpto" and import into "@abcd"

[image]

For pipelines, export the pipeline to JSON or YAML and Import to "@abcd". Pay attention to the resources the imported pipeline relies on(e.g. agent pool, service connection, Azure resource), you need to re-configure them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I try to use the Azure DevOps Migration Tools (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) on the board won't it work because the tenants are different?

Comment: Hi, you could use this tool to work with Azure DevOps Boards migration. It works between different tenants.